# How to see questions of specific tag with no upvoted answers

Tags: bug, tags, unanswered-questions

Hello I  just want to see [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag questions with no upvoted answers. For this I clicked on `UnAnswered` tab then it show me all types of questions C/C++/JS/Android. Here I want to filter only [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) but this is not working

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes

[image]

Here When I clicked on android then it redirected to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=votes&pageSize=50) and Here it should show only [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) questions with no upvotes answers but it is opening different (questions tagged) see in below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Your circles must be red: VLQ

Comment: @bjb568 Does it matter ?

Comment: Matter? ***Matter?!?!?!*** Nah, I don't really care.

Answer (score 7):

When you are in the [unanswered questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered), you can see few popular tags under the questions statistics:

> [image]

You can direct click on it to get questions with no upvoted answers with specific tag. E.g. [Android questions with no upvoted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android).

However if you don't see your tag you can manually add a tag via URL. Syntax is as follow:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/<tag-name>
```

E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/sql-server (which is not listed there)

Comment: Yes Well but this is some strange behavior because when you go bounty questions and you click on `android` as I did then it filters out the questions. No need to click on the list of tags that appear in right. Same behavior of others as well but not this which I asked

Comment: @MartijnPieters - That is for questions with "no answers". While this includes questions with no **upvoted** answers.

Comment: Yeah, I see that it's a different route, indeed.

Comment: @TGMCians - This seems strange but it isn't if you are familiar with SO. SE keeps your last visited tab as default. So when you click on the bounty tab then clicks on android tag it actually opens this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) but you are redirected to the bounty tab because you last visited it. Regarding that unanswered tab. That is totally different URL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions vs http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) that's why you are not redirecting to the unanswered tab when you click on specific tag.

Comment: Agreed but this should be handled perfectly . No matter from where I was