# Show only Stack Overflow questions that do not have an answer

Tags: discussion, search

Is there a way, at Stack Overflow, or any Stack Exchange page, to filter questions that do **not** have a posted (accepted or not accepted) answer?

Comment: Type answers:0 in the search bar

Comment: Yes, there is also an option in filter: http://prntscr.com/1va1ar8

Comment: Custom filter for [newest questions having no answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=Newest&filters=NoAnswers&edited=true).

Comment: You can also find questions that don't have an _accepted_ answer using by typing `hasaccepted:0` in the search (and you can do the same thing using custom filters). See [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for a list of all available operators.

Comment: Thanks ! But it seems like that it does not keep the highligt of the tags I've set as favourite e.g "python" (those questions are yellow w/o the filter, but white with)

Comment: @41686d6564 what you typically mostly see on `hasaccepted:0` are questions with answers that haven't been accepted yet (if they have answers)

Comment: @WietsedeVries Yes, that's the purpose of the hasaccepted operator. I'm just pointing out to the OP that there's a separate operator to look for questions with/without an accepted answer.

Comment: @41686d6564 I guess how I worded that it sounds like I'm just repeating the definition. What I mean is that it's often the case that these questions have answers that fully answer the question, therefore your help is not needed there anymore, they just haven't been accepted yet.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251039/how-to-see-questions-of-specific-tag-with-no-upvoted-answers

Comment: If you're looking at a specific tag (or multiple tags), you have the 'Unanswered' tab

Comment: @Mark The "Unanswered" filter is supremely strange in that, despite its name, it actually filters out "[questions with no upvoted or accepted answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur3rp.png)", rather than questions with _zero_ answers. I've never understood why it works that way.

Comment: @zcoop98 Because no upvotes or acceptance is an indication that existing answers don't actually answer the question (it might be inexact, but a pretty good indication, and you can easily clear questions that you think have been answered by upvoting answers).